# What pattern i need for url with semicolon in url in django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework

I have the url like this

```
http://www.example.com/user;age=9;name=dsds-dsds-ddd
```

Now i have this url of POST

```
url(r'^user$',
    views.CreateView.as_view(),
    name='user-create')
```

Now i also want to match the above url with semicolon separated parameters.

I am not able to find

1. What url pattern to define
2. How to grab those parameters in view

I tried this

```
url(r'^user;(?P<params>)$',
```

Comment: Could you not use a GET query or POST the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if django has APPEND_SLASH feature enabled which likely forces you add a slash `/` at the end of every URL that can be an issue.

Try doing this:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<myparams>[\w;.]/$',
    views.CreateView.as_view(),
    name='user-create')
```

Your URL in this case has to be something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/user/;age=9;name=dsds-dsds-ddd
```

django will automatically append a `/` at the end and convert it as:

```
http://www.example.com/user/;age=9;name=dsds-dsds-ddd/
```

Comment: any way without adding slash

Comment: @JohnKaff yes, but it can be dangerous just for the sake of info this will do it `url(r'^user(?P<myparams>[\w;.]', views.CreateView.as_view(), name='user-create')` or if you like @doniyor method to handle it you can do it as `url(r'^user', views.test)`

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
url(r'^user/', views.test)
```

views.py

```
from urllib import unquote

def test(request):
    url_with_semicolon = unquote(request.get_full_path())
    print url_with_semicolon.split(';')[1:]
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

input:

```
http://www.example.com/user/age=9;name=dsds-dsds-ddd
```

output:

```
[u'age=9', u'name=dsds-dsds-ddd']
```

hope, this helps you

Comment: is there any way without adding slash